# Can I chain where clauses conditionally?

Tags: python, orm, peewee

I'm using Peewee as ORM extensively and within my DAO API layer I need to conditionally make a query narrower e.g.

```
query = UserModel.select().where(UserModel.last_name == last_name)
if first_name is not None:
   query = query.where(UserModel.first_name == first_name)

# ... more conditions then

df = pd.DataFrame(query.dicts())
```

is this the most idiomatic way to conditionally make the queries narrower in Peewee or is there another way? Are there any pros and cons of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to doing first the dynamic condition and then calling where clause.

```py
query = UserModel.select()
filtered = UserModel.last_name == last_name

if first_name is not None:
   filtered &= UserModel.first_name == first_name
   
# ... more conditions then

# if some_cond:
#    filtered &= some_other_cond

# if some_cond:
#    filtered |= some_other_cond
 
# put one or other depending on
# the logic of your function 

query = query.where(filtered)

df = pd.DataFrame(query.dicts())
```

Edit : fix an error in the code

Comment: thanks a lot. Please note that you are already chaining the `where` call :) two times ...

Comment: "I would suggest to doing first the dynamic ..." why?

Comment: @SkyWalker could you please elaborate more your question ?

Comment: Yes, sure, thanks! why do you state or imply that is better the way of your answer compared to chaining `where` clauses. I would like to know concretely why what you suggest is better or the correct way if possible with references to the Peewee documentation as I searched and couldn't find any information on this topic.

Comment: I think it is the same doing my way, `doing the condition first and calling where` and `calling chaining where method or orwhere`.

according to Peewee docs 

This note is really important:

`where() calls are chainable. Multiple calls will be “AND”-ed together.`



https://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/api.html?highlight=orwhere%20#Query.where

you can call also `orwhere` if you want to chain conditions with OR operator.

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can do this a couple ways:

```
# Chaining calls to .where() will AND the clauses together.
q = q.where(Model.field == 'something')
q = q.where(Model.other == 'another')

# Another option:
accum = []
accum.append(Model.field == 'something')
accum.append(Model.other == 'another')
q = q.where(*accum)

# Or you can explicitly AND them together:
q = q.where(reduce(operator.and_, accum))
```

Etc.